# Why do I have the same Python version in different environments?

Tags: python, environment

I created different environments for different bioinformatic tools because I knew they would each require their own version of python. However, I am having troubles running one program and I think it's because of the python version. When I run the program on my own computer, as opposed to a HPC, I use the same version of the program but with Python 3.7.12 and it works. This python version is different than my base, and the other environments on my local computer.

On the HPC, in the environment folder of the program, it shows there are Python 3.7 and Python 3 folders, but when I check which python is being run in that environment, it says it is Python 2.7.5. When I switch environments to see what version of python is being used (i.e. python --version), they all say Python 2.7.5.... Is there a way to switch python versions in a given environment?

I've tried re-installing python in the environment and specifying the version (i.e. conda install python=3.7.0), but it still says Python 2.7.5 when I check the version.

Comment: Have you tried `python3` instead of `python`? The default system python may be 2.

Comment: Ah thank you!!! This works! I can see I have different versions of python in my environments and when I run my program with python3 instead of just python in front, it works! You are the best!